# Point farthest away from ray

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I have a couple of points in 3D space and I need to find the one which  has the biggest normal distance away from a ray defined by two points $P0$ and $P1$.
When I calculate $d = |({P0 - P1})\times({P1 - P})|$ the magnitude of the cross product for each point $P$ and take the maximum, it seems that I get the point that has the biggest normal distance starting from the ray. I know that the magnitude of the cross product is equal to the area of the parallelogram spanned by both vectors. So my assumption is that the bigger the area of the parallelogram, the farther away a point is from the ray. But I can't prove that my assumption is correct.

Comment: The area of a parallelogram is just $bh$. Can you use this to either prove or disprove your assertion? Think about two points that are at equal heights, one is very far away in the horizontal direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my assumption is that the bigger the area of the parallelogram, the farther away a point is from the ray

Consider a ray starting at the point $P_0 = (0, 0)$ and going infinitely far in the direction of $P_1 = (1, 0)$. Now consider a point $P_2 = (0, 1)$ and a point $P_3 = (-10,000, 1)$. We note that $\|P_3 - P_0\| > \|P_2 - P_0\|$, yet $\|(P_1 - P_0) \times (P_2 - P_0)\| = \|(P_1 - P_0) \times (P_3 - P_0)\|$.

A simple way to see this is just from thinking about the area of a parallelogram as $bh$, and thus we see that we only care about the height of the point, so we can translate it horizontally arbitrarily far.

Comment: Maybe a dump question but what does the T mean in $\mathbf{x} = [1, 0]^T$? Transpose?

Comment: Yeah. This is often done if you want a column vector in-line, you just write it as a row vector and take the transpose

Comment: Ok I don't get it. I don't understand what you mean with "Now compare the distances of (20, 1) and (1, 0) from the vector x. Obviously these points are not equidistant from the ray". The ray x is at (0, 0) and goes along (1, 0). The distance from x to  y is 1. The distance from x to z is also 1. So the distances are actually the same.

Comment: Well I think that I even have a proof now: As you said, $A = b*h$. $b$ is constant since it is always $P1- P0$. So the only variable that can change the value of $A$ is $h$. $h$ is dependent on how far each point $P$ is away from $P1 - P0$. The farther a point is away from $P1 - P0$, the bigger $h$ becomes and thus, the bigger the area of the parallelogram becomes.

Comment: @NMO I've edited the question to reflect what you've said. Notice that I can go arbitrarily far way from the ray horizontally to make the distance go to $\infty$, but the area of the parallelogram remains unchanged.

Comment: The fallacy is in "The farther a point is away from P1−P0, the bigger h becomes and thus, the bigger the area of the parallelogram becomes". This is not true precisely because I can increase distance while maintaining the same area by shifting the point horizontally away from the ray.

Comment: Your are right with saying that $\|P_3 - P_0\| > \|P_2 - P_0\|$ but when I talk about the distance of a point from a ray, then I'm talking about the normal distance. I have edited my question to make that clearer, although it should be clear. You are taking an arbitrary point on the ray (P0) and calculate the distances from this point. But this doesn't make sense, since it is a ray and not a line segment.

Comment: If what you mean by "normal" is orthogonal distance, then you are correct, but this is not what the question said originally. If you mean Euclidean distance, then my answer stands.